# Want to add Javascript code/ Script tag in angular component ts/html file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have written frontend in Angular. I am using driver.js npm package for web tour guide. That package has close, previous and next button.

Driver.js docs:- https://kamranahmed.info/driver.js/

**GOAL**:- I want to add click event on close button.

**Problem**:-  There isn't any function in package to do some custom code on close button click event.

**My Idea**:- Seems like it will work if i add click event through script tag in html/ts file. But, i don't know how to add script tag nd add event on close button in component.

Can someone help me to figure out this?

Comment: `I don't know how to add script tag and add event on close button in component` --> You mean `(click)="clickHandler($event)"` ?

Comment: yes just like access element by its class/id and the add click event listener in script tag. @JeremyThille

Comment: Or if you have any other idea plz share. @JeremyThille

Comment: But this is an Angular application. You add a click event listener by doing `(click)="clickHandler($event)"`.

Comment: The close button is not in my component file. The popover html/css/js code is comming from driver package.

Comment: Ah well, in this case, I doubt it's going to be easy. Angular plays notoriously bad with vanilla JS, with things like `getElementById` or `querySelector`, which are "out of Angular's world". Your best bet would be to find an Angular version of DriverJS, or drop DriverJS and do everything yourself with Angular.